# Import DayOfWeek Name as Bit in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and have a database that includes the day of week in a bit type such as:

```
JobID           int
JobDescription  nvarchar(50)
M               bit
Tu              bit
W               bit
Th              bit
F               bit
Sa              bit
Su              bit
```

I need to import data from an Excel spreadsheet that has rows and they identify the value as a name such as:

```
100 Backup      Monday
101 Reports     Monday
102 Cleaning    Tuesday
```

So I would need this to show up for example

```
100 Backup      1   0   0   0   0   0   0
101 Reports     1   0   0   0   0   0   0
102 Cleaning    0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

I have several thousand rows of this and can't seem to think of a way to import this data. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First import file as is into temp table and then insert into destination table from:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(JobID INT, JobDescription NVARCHAR(MAX), DayOfTheWeek NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(100, 'Backup', 'Monday'),
(101, 'Reports', 'Monday'),
(102, 'Cleaning', 'Tuesday')


SELECT  JobID, 
        JobDescription,
        CASE WHEN DayOfTheWeek = 'Monday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS M,
        CASE WHEN DayOfTheWeek = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Tu,
        CASE WHEN DayOfTheWeek = 'Wednsday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS W,
        CASE WHEN DayOfTheWeek = 'Thusday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Th,
        CASE WHEN DayOfTheWeek = 'Friday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS F,
        CASE WHEN DayOfTheWeek = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Sa,
        CASE WHEN DayOfTheWeek = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Su
FROM @t
```

Output:

```
JobID   JobDescription  M   Tu  W   Th  F   Sa  Su
100     Backup          1   0   0   0   0   0   0
101     Reports         1   0   0   0   0   0   0
102     Cleaning        0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a two-step solution to your problem.  First, you can generate 7 columns representing the bits for each day of the week using Excel.  The following screen captures show how you can do this:

[image]

[image]

In each column for a given day of the week, I use a formula to check whether 0 or 1 should go there.

The next step is to export the file as CSV from Excel, using commas as a delimeter.  Once you have done this, you can import this file into SQL Server.

```
BULK INSERT YourTable
FROM 'YourCSV.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
```

And the output will be the same as with Giorgi's method:

```
JobID   JobDescription  M   Tu  W   Th  F   Sa  Su
100     Backup          1   0   0   0   0   0   0
101     Reports         1   0   0   0   0   0   0
102     Cleaning        0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

The method I use let's you stay within the comforts of Excel to handle the messy part of the data scrubbing.  Only in the last step do we bring the data into SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Obviusly you need: first, read the excel file. The bit array for the week goes from 0 to 6, so for each row read you have the correct array for the values. Every row from the excel will be an sql statement insert into (...) values (code,task,0,1,0...0). Save all the queries and execute at the end.